# How do i import an image in pygame on mac?

Tags: python, pygame

So im trying to  load an image with pygame but i don't know exactly what its supposed to look and all the examples I've seen are from people on windows  and the ones on mac don't seem to help.

This is what I'm currently trying but it doesn't work and says there is no such file or directory as this.

```
sky_surface = pygame.image.load('/Macintosh HD/Users/Amin/Desktop/Sky.png').convert()
```

I do have an image called 'Sky.png' on my desktop.

[screenshot of image directory as shown in finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwkfZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `Macintosh  HD` should not be a part of the pathname -- the correct path should be, in your case here, `/Users/Amin/Desktop/Sky.png`.

MacOS (I'm on Monterey now) should have a feature to copy a pathname of a file. In Finder you may right-click on a file to get the context menu and then press `option` key. You should see the `Copy ... as Pathname` entry. This will copy the valid pathname to your clipboard -- and as you'll see, it won't contain `Macintosh HD` prefix.

Comment: your solution worked thank you but when i tried the feature to copy  a pathname of the file after pressing options i did not get copy .. as pathname entry

Comment: @AminAlim, sorry, I edited the answer --> right click, see the menu, click options and you should see that entry. Alternatively you can command+option+c on a file to get the same effect